# VBA procedure access level

Tags: excel, vba, module, procedure

I would like to make a quick question and very basic on VBA...

I found this fine explanation on the web on VBA procedures:

*Like a variable access, the access to a procedure can be controlled by an access level. A            procedure can be made private or public. To specify the access level of a procedure, 
precede it with the Private or the Public keyword.*

Next it goes as...

*The rules that were applied to global variables are the same:*

*Private: If a procedure is made private, it can be called by other procedures of the same module. Procedures of outside modules cannot access such a procedure.
Also, when a procedure is private, its name does not appear in the Macros dialog box*

*Public: A procedure created as public can be called by procedures of the same module and by procedures of other modules.
Also, if a procedure was created as public, when you access the Macros dialog box, its name appears and you can run it from there*

And its great, crystal clear! The only thing i wonder is **what is the access level** of a procedure declared **without a Public or Private function?**

minor question
Also if we have a Public keyword can the procedure by called by modules **of other** workbooks?

**Thank you for seeing my question**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Procedures are `Public` by default.

Procedures marked `Public` **can** be called by other workbooks **unless** you write `Option Private Module` at the top of the module containing the procedure.

Comment: Thank you! A perfect answer! But i will be able to tick it as correct in 10 minutes according to the site rules!

Comment: To add to his answer: The way to call a procedure from another workbook is `Application.Run("NameOfWorkbook.xlm!MyFunction")`. If you need to send it parameters, it's like this : `Application.Run("NameOfWorkbook.xlm!MyFunction", 20, 34, etc...)`

Comment: So procedure that is like that                                      Sub Shmoo                                                                              End Sub                                                               and it doesn't have the Public keyword is public only in the scope of the Workbook is in right?                                        Now if i mark it with the Public keyword as a foreword the ONLY difference is that it can be read by modules in other workbooks. Is that correct?

Comment: Well i now wonder of one thing:                                      If a procedure without a public keyword is public by default, do we use the Public as a mark in the foreword section to enhance the access level from the workbook we are in to other workbooks that are open?

Comment: @ExoticBirdsMerchant it's really easy to TRY IT YOURSELF!